# Find the remainder when $2^{2016}$ is divided by $9$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, chinese-remainder-theorem

How to find the remainder of $2^{2016}$ divided by $9$?

The possible prime factor of $2^{2016}$ is $2$ and the possible prime factor of $9$ is $3$. So the remainder should be non zero.

Give some hints. Thanks in advance.

Comment: $2^3 \equiv -1 \pmod{9}$

Answer (score 8):

Here is a HINT

$2^6=64=1 \mod 9$

Comment: Can you post full answer with proper explanation,please?

Comment: @user322806 people here are usually not fond of doing your homework for you. Can you write $2^{2016}$ using $2^6$?

Comment: @user322806 Bram28 has provided you a more than sufficient hint to find the answer yourself. This site encourages effort on your part instead of spoon feeding you the solutions. For more information, visit the [help centre](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/asking).

Comment: I got it. Thanks much.

Comment: @user322806 You're welcome!:)

Answer (score 5):

By the binomial theorem, $2^{2016} = (3-1)^{2016} = 9a - 2016\cdot 3 +1 = 9b+1$.

Comment: What are $a$ and $b$?

Comment: @tilper whatever integers